# Javaee 7 SSL cipher suite

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ssl, glassfish, rsa

I'm quite newbie in SSL certificates and cipher suites that's why I ask for help. I have a GF4 server and standalone client. Client connects to server via iiop ssl. Client shows no exceptions but it hangs. With javax.net.debug I see that there endlessly appears the following information at client:

```
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
```

At the same time for used certificates I see Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]. What does it all mean? Should I add some cipher suite to GF. If yes, than which one?

Comment: I believe it means your server keystore does not have any private keys in it. Since you are the server and you have no RSA private key, you cannot possibly complete a negotiation involving an RSA ciphersuite. Ditto for DSA and ECDSA.

Comment: @GregS Thank you for your time. My glassfish keystore.jks has two entries:1)Alias name: glassfish-instance Creation date: Jun 4, 2014 Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry 2)Alias name: s1as Creation date: Jun 4, 2014 Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry. Is it not enough? What should I do?

Comment: @GregS I generated DSA certificate to GF keystore. After that exported it and imported it to client truststore. After that changed certificate alias for iiop. The result is the same. Can you explain what you meant?

Comment: Do you have source code for the client? If so, when you get the SSLSocket from the Factory class, you need to call setEnabledCipherSuites()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my situation I solved this problem because I noticed that everything works only if the client and javaee server are at the same host. That's why I understood and asked the RIGHT question and I found the answer by myself. If you are interested in it, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24123117/2022068