# JavaEE - EJB over SSL works only if client and server are at the same host

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ssl, glassfish, rsa

Please help me. I can do nothing with it. I have gf 4.0.1 and swing client. I want to get EJB over SSL. I've set all certificates. However, I can get it work only when client and server are at the same host. What I see in tcpdump when they are at the same host:

```
........ 
10.0.17.2.48524 > 10.0.17.2.3820: Flags [P.], cksum 0x378f (incorrect -> 0xf2b6), seq 399:756, ack 1085, win 273, options [nop,nop,TS val 347297976 ecr 347297966], length 357
13:01:26.334898 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 51559, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 665)
    10.0.17.2.3820 > 10.0.17.2.48524: Flags [P.], cksum 0x388f (incorrect -> 0x626d), seq 1085:1698, ack 756, win 273, options [nop,nop,TS val 347297977 ecr 347297976], length 613
13:01:26.374075 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 39617, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.0.17.2.48524 > 10.0.17.2.3820: Flags [.], cksum 0x9282 (correct), seq 756, ack 1698, win 289, options [nop,nop,TS val 347298017 ecr 347297977], length 0
13:01:26.375662 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 15848, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    127.0.0.1.42403 > 127.0.0.1.3820: Flags [S], cksum 0x7255 (correct), seq 2517132554, win 32792, options [mss 16396,sackOK,TS val 347298018 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
13:01:26.375678 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    127.0.0.1.3820 > 127.0.0.1.42403: Flags [S.], cksum 0x21e9 (correct), seq 2013817557, ack 2517132555, win 32768, options [mss 16396,sackOK,TS val 347298018 ecr 347298018,nop,wscale 7], length 0
........
```

That is it starts working from one ip and port but at some places it changes ip to 127.0.0.1 and a new connection is established: 10.0.17.2.3820 > 10.0.17.2.48524 (client port 48524) and then 127.0.0.1.3820 > 127.0.0.1.42403 (client port 42403).

When client and server at different host I don't get any exception but the client hangs. On server in log I have:

```
[2014-06-09T13:09:07.367+0400] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=139 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1402304947367] [levelValue: 800] [[
  p: thread-pool-1; w: 1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48]]
[2014-06-09T13:09:07.367+0400] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=139 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1402304947367] [levelValue: 800] [[
  %% Cached server session: [Session-15, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]]]
[2014-06-09T13:09:07.404+0400] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=139 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1402304947404] [levelValue: 800] [[
  p: thread-pool-1; w: 1, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 352]]
[2014-06-09T13:09:07.408+0400] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=139 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1402304947408] [levelValue: 800] [[
  p: thread-pool-1; w: 1, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 608]]
```

And on client I get endlessly the following message (with different cipher suite):

```
.......
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
.......
```

How can it be fixed? Full client log is here http://centr-kav.org/temp.txt

Comment: Enable more cipher suites on the client? `127.0.0.1` is not a port, it's an IP address of the localhost.

Comment: @owlstead Thank you for your time. I know that 127.0.0.1 is not a port :) I meant that at the beggining it was 10.0.17.2.3820 > 10.0.17.2.48524 (client port 48524) and then 127.0.0.1.42403 > 127.0.0.1.3820 (client port 42403). Please, can you say in details what chiper suite I must enable and how. Or at least what chiper.

Comment: @owlstead I edited the question to be clearer.

Comment: @owlstead I've looked at your profile and saw you are expert in security. That's why I ask you for help, as it's second year I can't do it and without anyone's help I won't do it. Just a clue. Just a hint. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: I'm afraid there is not much information for me to go on. You should post Glassfish configurations. I'm not a super-expert on SSL, and I'm certainly not a Glashfish expert, so I may be not much of help here (the only thing I ever did with Glashfish is to decide against using WSDL security on it and program it myself because I could not verify its security - just before the padding oracle attacks were found on it).

Comment: @owlstead Here I put all client log http://centr-kav.org/temp.txt What I can see is that it says: 1)Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA 2)%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA] but in unsupported and unavailable there is no such cipher.

Comment: @owlstead I found the reason.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. I hope that it will be useful for someone. The problem was that server redirected client to 127.0.0.1. The reason was that

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost()
```

returned 127.0.0.1 on my Linux machine. The reason was that I didn't set /etc/host. And that's why

```
hostname -i
```

returned 127.0.0.1

After editing /etc/hosts it's not necessary to restart server, only to restart glassfish. Also at domain.xml I added:

```
<jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.CORBA.ORBServerHost=x.x.x.x</jvm-options>
```

Also see https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-4051

Comment: @unwichtich Ufortunately I can do it only in two days - this is the rule of system. But if you like the answer you can upvote for it :). It was really very difficult question.